# Creating styles from Material-UI theme that can be reused across components?

Tags: material-ui

In Material-UI 4, one can easily create styles that can be used inside a component. I use the `makeStyles()` function for this.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    hoverableContent: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark
        }
    }
}));

const MyComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    ...
}
```

However, I would like to reuse this style in multiple components. What is the best way to do this in Material-Ui 4?

*Note: I think of this as a slightly higher level abstraction: sharing abstract classes (in a controlled way) instead of just colors (in a theme).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

1. Share the style between your components

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    hoverableContent: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark
        }
    }
})
```

This approach then leads to this question. How do you merge multiple styles? https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11517

2. Generate a global class name and apply it where it makes sense. But be careful with class name conflict and tree-shaking

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is a bit late, however i just faced it and solved by making a hook:

```
// someSharedClasses.ts
export default makeStyles((theme)=>createStyles({
    hoverableContent: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark
        }
    }
}));
```

And other component:

```
import useSharedClasses from './someSharedClasses.ts';
const MyComponent = () => {
  const sharedClasses = useSharedClasses();
  // use sharedClasses.hoverableContent as className
}
```